# Как передать в balloonContentBody параметры?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Есть файл data.json в котором хранятся данные по разным меткам. Все метки создаются, но я не понимаю как в balloonContentBody вставить параметры из json файла?

Вот пример файла json:

```
{
  "Points":
  [
    {
      "MapPointTitle": "Любино",
      "MapPointCoordinates": "55.791901, 37.626301"
    },

    {
      "MapPointTitle": "Никита",
      "MapPointCoordinates": "55.418471, 37.947814"
    }
  ]
}
```

Вот сам файл JS

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var map = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [55.76, 37.57],
        zoom: 5,
        controls: ['zoomControl', 'searchControl']
    });
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        // Создадим объект точек из data.Points
        var myGeoObjects = data.Points.map(item => {
            return new ymaps.GeoObject({
                geometry: {
                    type: "Point",
                    // Переведем строку с координатами в массив
                    coordinates: item.MapPointCoordinates.split(', ')
                },
                properties: {
                    clusterCaption: 'Описание в кластере',
                    balloonContentBody: [
                        '<address style="font-style: normal">',
                        '<h3>Данные</h3>',
                        '<b>Координаты: </b> <br>',
                        '</address>'
                    ].join('')
                }
            }, {
                preset: "islands#darkGreenDotIcon",
            });
        })
        // Создадим кластеризатор после получения и добавления точек
        var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
            preset: 'islands#invertedDarkGreenClusterIcons',
            clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
            clusterBalloonContentLayoutWidth: 800,
            clusterBalloonLeftColumnWidth: 160
        });
        clusterer.add(myGeoObjects);
        map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
        map.setBounds(clusterer.getBounds(), {
            checkZoomRange: true
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В песочнице API Яндекс.Карт есть пример на нужную вам тему:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager

Пример структуры файла:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 0, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.831903, 37.411961]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.763338, 37.565466]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}}
 ]
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но если мне нужно ещё повесить кнопку которая будет считывать строку адреса? Как её можно будет обработать? Ведь в json формате это не сделать

Comment: непонятен вопрос. Какую кнопку, куда повесить? Какая у вас задача?

Comment: Вот добавлены стали метки, у каждой из них свой адрес. Я его отдельно вывожу в описании у метки. И необходимо, что бы была возможно выбрать метку, то есть запомнить и записать её адрес.